# Merge two different Django migrations

Tags: django, merge, migration

We have two developers working on Django. Due to some technical issues we have not started using version control yet. The two developers did some changes to the django models. Developer A has 1 migration and the developer B has 5 migrations. They both worked in two different tables. How do I go about merging the two migrations if they did not use version control.

Comment: How about `./manage.py makemigrations --merge`?

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but I think it's possible to just copy-paste migrations and change their names, as long as they for separate tables.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the migrations have the same number on prefix.
Keep the original name on the first one and increment the second.
For instance:

```
Developer A: 0035_customer.py
Developer B: 0035_process.py -> rename to -> 0036_process.py
```

Additionally, change the `dependencies` attribute on second migration to make sure that will run in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have two different migration like `001_add_x` and `002_add_y` and both of them have been applied to the database.

When you want to merge them and create a new migration like `003_add_z` in the merged project, you should run

`python manage.py migrate <app> 001 --fake`

and

`python manage.py migrate <app> 002 --fake`

and then you can run

`python manage.py migrate <app>`

or you can delete all migration file and re-run makemigration to create migration for all models, then you can run `migrate <app> --fake`